# Upgrade AWS Windows Server 2019 to Insider Preview

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-server, windows-server-2019, windows-insider

I have an instance of windows server 2019 base running on aws and would like to install the windows server insider preview. Updating the settings for windows update in group policy editor did not bring up the insider settings tab so I opted to install from iso. The install started successfully and closed the rdp window due to a restart. However, I am not able to connect to the instance afterwards even after waiting for the cpu activity to settle for a while in the ec2 dashboard. The "keep my data and settings" option was grayed out, not sure if that had any impact on the final result. Could this be an issue with the install resetting rdp to disabled? If so, is enabling rdp through remote registry the only way to fix this?

Comment: I don't even believe Windows Server 2019 is even eligible for Insider Preview builds since Windows Server 2019 is based on Windows 10 version 1809.  There wouldn't be any eligible builds it could receive.  Only Windows Server version 20H2, which is licensed different than Windows Server 2019, is eligible for Insider Preview builds.

Comment: Ah seems like the best bet is Azure then, right?